# Binding async method into DropDownList ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

**MachineDto:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
[Display(Name = "Hardware Type")]
public string HardwareType { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListOfHardwares { get; set; }
```

**IHardwareRepository:**

```
public interface IHardwareRepository
{
Task<Entities.Hardware>> GetAllHardwareAsync();
}
```

**HardwareRepository**:

```
public async Task<List<Entities.Hardware>> GetAllHardwareAsync()
        {
            var getAllHardware = await _appContext.Hardwares.ToListAsync();

            return getAllHardware;
        }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HardwareType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HardwareType, Model.ListOfHardwares, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HardwareType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

***EDIT***:

**Controller:**

```
public class HardwareController : Controller
    {
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public HardwareController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

public async Task<ActionResult> DisplayAll()
        {
            var displayAll = await _unitOfWork.HardwareRepository.GetAllHardwareAsync();

            return View(displayAll);
        }
}
```

**EDIT2:**
**Controller:**

```
> public async Task<ActionResult> Add()
>         {
>             var model = new ImageDto();
>             var hardwares = await _unitOfWork.HardwareRepository.GetAllHardwareAsync();
> 
>             model.ListOfHardwares = hardwares.Select(h => new SelectListItem
>             {
>                 Text = h.Name,
>                 Value = h.Description
>             });
> 
>             return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MachineDto

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HardwareType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Model.ListOfHardwares, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HardwareType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

The problem is that now I want to pass GetAllHardwareAsync to ListOfHardwares and display it via DropDownList. I don't really want to do it by ViewBag. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you simply need to set the value on the model using an instance of the repository.  *Where* you do this depends on where you have (or can get) an instance of the repository and where you want to set the value on the model.

For example, in the majority of cases, the repository would be on the controller and the controller would build the model to send to the view.  Which might look something like this...

```
private IHardwareRepository _repository;

public SomeController(IHardwareRepository repository)
{
    // I'm *assuming* you get the repository from dependency injection
    _repository = repository;
}

public async Task<ActionResult> SomeAction()
{
    var model = new MachineDto();
    model.ListOfHardwares = await _repository.GetAllHardwaresAsync();
    return View(model);
}
```

If you're not using dependency injection, perhaps you'd just instantiate your repository directly?  Something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SomeAction()
{
    var repository = new HardwareRepository();
    var model = new MachineDto();
    model.ListOfHardwares = await repository.GetAllHardwaresAsync();
    return View(model);
}
```

Though that would defeat much of the purpose of the interface.  It's really up to you how you manage your dependencies.  The point is that you simply need to populate your model before sending it to the view.  Then the elements on the view can bind to it.

**Edit:** Given your edit to the question, it looks like the repository is on a unit of work which is already injected into the controller.  In that case it might look like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DisplayAll()
{
    var model = new MachineDto();
    model.ListOfHardwares = await _unitOfWork.HardwareRepository.GetAllHardwareAsync();

    return View(model);
}
```

The view itself would of course also need the model declaration at the top, if you don't already have that (so it knows the model type):

```
@model MachineDto
```

**Edit:** On further inspection, it looks like your model wants an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` instead of just the actual data itself.  I generally recommend doing that sort of projection in the *view* instead of the model, but not strongly enough to really discourage this practice entirely.  Especially if this "model" is purely a view model for just this view.

In this case all you need is a simple projection.  Once you have your list of results, you can project it to the list of the type you need.  Something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DisplayAll()
{
    var model = new MachineDto();
    var hardwares = await _unitOfWork.HardwareRepository.GetAllHardwareAsync();
    model.ListOfHardwares = hardwares.Select(h => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = h.SomeTextProperty,
        Value = h.SomeIdentifierProperty
    });
    return View(model);
}
```

What you use for `SomeTextProperty` and `SomeIdentifierProperty` depends on what properties exist on `Hardware` and how you want to use those to build your select list.

Comment: If I write like you, then in: `model.ListOfHardwares = _unitOfWork.HardwareRepository.GetAllHardwaresAsync()` VS says that Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<NCR_Image_Manager.Entities.Hardware>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Xardas: You forgot the `await` keyword.  With `await`, the result is a `List<Entities.Hardware>`.  Without it, the result is a `Task<List<Entities.Hardware>>`.  As the error states, they are different types.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about await, but still its not resolving the issue.

Comment: @Xardas: Can you further describe the problem?  In what way is it failing?

Comment: MachineDto has the field HardWareType which is taken from ListOfHardwares. ListOfHardwares is taken directly from DB, because Hardwares can be put into Db separetely. So it means that i have separate repository for Hardware and Machine. The thing is that I want to pass return value from HardwareRepository(which is included in UnitOfWork btw.) to the ListOfHardwares in Machine. At first i Did it through ViewBag like this: `ViewBag.ListOfRpsw = new SelectList(_rpswRepository.GetAllRpsw(), "Name", "Description");` and it worked, but since I added async&await and UnitOfWork it stopped working.

Comment: @Xardas: It's not clear what all of that has to do with the code being discussed here.  First off, do you want to use a property on the model being sent to the view, or do you want to use `ViewBag`?  You need to pick one.  The question seemed to be focusing on using the model, not the `ViewBag`.  Once you choose one, focus on specifically *that* implementation.  In what specific way is *that* not working?  Currently you're asking how to do this with a model, and this answer demonstrates that, but then you say it's not working because your `ViewBag` implementation doesn't work.  Which is it?

Comment: You did not get me right. I was using ViewBag but I dont want use it anymore. I just said that solution with ViewBag was working back then. But still I DONT WANT to use ViewBag

Comment: @Xardas: Then what specifically isn't working *now*?  When you debug, where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: `model.ListOfHardwares = await _unitOfWork.HardwareRepository.GetAllHardwaresAsync();` - here, it says like i pasted error above.

Comment: @Xardas: What is the exact error?  The error you mentioned in your first comment above would certainly be expected from the line of code in that comment.  But you've corrected that line of code.  If there's still an error of some kind, surely it says something else.  If it doesn't, you're misrepresenting something somewhere.

Comment: It says exactly:Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<NCR_Image_Manager.Entities.Hardware>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Xardas: Which is a *different* error than the one pasted in the first comment above.  It's important to carefully read error messages.  It looks like your model property is actually a list of `SelectListItems`?  Kind of strange, which is likely why I admittedly overlooked that.  But not a problem.  I'll update the answer to reflect the projection needed to create that list...

Comment: @Xardas: Answer updated.  Let me know if there's still an issue!

Comment: Ok, I think we are getting closer, but...now i have error in MachineView here: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HardwareType, Model.ListOfHardwares, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })` that Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Xardas: What specifically is `null` in that line?  `Model`?  Are you successfully passing the model to the view?  Does the view include the model declaration at the top?  Are you able to use any other properties on the model?  Is something else `null`?

Comment: The model declaration at the top is: @model namespace.MachineDto. i am able to use other properties.

Comment: @Xardas: Don't assume, debug.  Note that I can't see the current state of your code.  All I can see is what you've shown and the suggestions made to correct it.

Comment: Ok, now I am sure that ListOfHardwares is null.

Comment: @Xardas: Go ahead and add an edit to your question demonstrating the updated state of how you're populating the model and returning it to the view, and how the view is using the model.

Comment: take a look now and let me know what do you think.

Comment: @Xardas: You're not sending the model to the view: `return View();`  Should be: `return View(model);`

Comment: Omg, you're the best! I will mark ur answear as the best one of course. Additional question: if I have, lets say 5 lists, do i need to write 5 times more code in controller, separately for each list?

Comment: @Xardas: Well, if you're populating 5 properties on your model, that would certainly imply 5 lines of code to populate those properties.